# VSCode pausing where there is no breakpoint

Tags: visual-studio-code, webpack, vscode-debugger

VSCode keeps pausing on a file called `hot module replacement` which looks like it's a part of webpack.

[image: vscode paused on if (me.hot.active) {]

I have no break points at all.

[image]

Launch config

```json
    {
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "trace": true,
      "name": "Launch vscode not extension",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",

      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```

How do I stop this?

Comment: I get this all the time doing `Flutter` development in `VSCode` - it acts as if it has hit a break point, always within a package dependency, not my own code, and there is no exception, but it says "Paused on pause".  So annoying, and I can't find any information about it.

Comment: I never used to get this, now all of a sudden I'm getting it. Not sure if it's related to my flutter sdk upgrade. What I do now is "flutter run" from the terminal in VS code then click on the link it shows in the terminal after the wording: "The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler" . No fake breakpoints or real ones get hit

Answer (score 1):

[image]

My problem was that my CALL STACK would say "Paused on pause",
when I had no breakpoints set up, and also no Exceptions were shown.

However, I think is is just bad UI in VSCode,
because actually a code error is occurring.

When I resume processing by pressing the Play button ..

[image]

If I have the DEBUG CONSOLE open, then after I hit the Play button again to get past this alleged "Paused on pause" then an error inevitably does appear in the console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the launch.json file the line "stopAtEntry": false, exists. Mine was true so it paused for no reason.